# How to look for files contain a character in name

Tags: .net, powershell

I'm searching for files containing a specific character in their name. When found the file name and path will be written on text file.

```
$filePath = "c:", "d:"
$fileName = "~"
$computerName = Get-Content env:computername
$srvPath = "\\server\share$\FindFileScript\$computerName.txt"

#SEARCH FOR FILE ON C DISK
$fileResult = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force $filePath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
| Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*$fileName*" } | Select-Object FullName | format-Table * -AutoSize)
if ($fileResult -eq $Null)
{
Write-Host "File named $fileName on disk C was not found."
}
Else
{
Write-Host "File named $fileName on disk C was found."
Out-File -FilePath $srvPath -InputObject $fileResult
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was some code I found worked better.

```
cls
write-Host "---------------------------------------------" -ForegroundColor Yellow
$filePath = Read-Host "Please Enter File Path to Search" 
write-Host "---------------------------------------------" -ForegroundColor Red
$fileName = Read-Host "Please Enter File Name to Search" 
write-Host "---------------------------------------------" -ForegroundColor Yellow
"`n" 

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force $filePath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object { ($_.PSIsContainer -eq $false) -and  ( $_.Name -like "*$fileName*") } | Select-Object Name,Directory| Format-Table -AutoSize * 

write-Host "------------END of Result--------------------" -ForegroundColor Magenta 

# end of the script
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not make it really simple

```
gci -re -in "*~*" | %{ $_.FullName } | out-file $srvPath
```

Comment: I'm new to powershell so could you possibly explain what your code does.

Comment: `gci` is the alias for Get-ChildItem, `-re` is `-Recursive`, `-in` is `-Include` (filters results).  `% {$_.FullName}` will return the full name and path as output and `out-file $srvPath` pipes the output to the file defined in `$srvPath`